# Need to display a error message but as form is getting updated , its not getting displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to display a error message on click of a command button : the error is thrown when the exception occurs at getting the row count in load() method inside LazyDataModel . I am usinf primefaces 4.0 version

and I am adding a error message in the backing bean 
public void showup() {

```
    if(flag){
         addMessage(MessageBundleEnum.BUSINESSLOGIC.getMessage("error158"));

         RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("mainForm:messages");
    }
```

and command button looks like : my command button looks like

```
        <p:outputPanel id="findCriteriaButtonGroup" layout="block" styleClass="buttonGroup">
            <p:commandButton id="criteria_find" icon="ui-icon-search" accesskey="F" action="#{backingBean.findCriteria}" update="@form" value="#{msg.button_FIND}" oncomplete="typeof resultsTable !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; resultsTable.getPaginator().setPage(0,true)" />

         </p:outputPanel>
    </ui:composition>
```

I can see that error message is being added to the messages but as the form is getting updated , my error message is getting wiped out , how can I handle this ?

Comment: Please include the messages tag declaration within the mainForm

Comment: Make you question a [mcve]

Comment: This question is only slightly better than your former one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581581/i-am-trying-to-display-a-message-on-click-of-a-command-button-in-primefaces